# Suppress errors for if(file_exists)

Tags: php, if-statement, error-handling, warnings, shorthand

I was wondering if suppressing warning for a method might ever be a better and shorter version of using  an if or shorthand if statement like so:

```
if(file_exists('a/file/path/that/doesnt/exist.file')) {

    unlink('a/file/path/that/doesnt/exist.file');

}
```

Possible shorter version:

```
@unlink('a/file/path/that/doesnt/exist.file');
```

If we are definitely sure, that the only problem that could occur during the unlink method is a 'file missing/not found' situation, and not anything else(permission denied etc.), would it be okay to simply suppress the unlink function?

Comment: What's wrong with the first example? I think it's a better idea to be definitive about your expectations in code

Comment: @RobbieAverill I just think the latter is a tiny bit faster than the first version as the code is shorter and PHP doesn't have to check whether the file exists or not. I am doing this to delete/create files in the number of thousands btw